# subpage with character /

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I need to add subpage with help `.htaccess` and I put in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1&galery=$2
```

and if i need to go to subpage i must put `domain/username&galery` But i dont need to use this `&` character. instead i need to use this `/` character. what should i change to get like this
 `domain/username/galery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&galery=$2 [L,QSA]
```